# run query with Mongodb in Symfony Framework

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony

I am new in mongodb.I run following query and my system will hangs.

```
$products = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')
    ->getManager()
    ->createQueryBuilder('AcmeStoreBundle:Product')
    ->field('name')->equals('foo')
    ->limit(10)
    ->sort('price', 'ASC')
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute();
   echo "<pre>";print_r($products);die;
```

I got this:

```
Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Cursor Object
(
    [baseCursor:Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Cursor:private] => Doctrine\MongoDB\LoggableCursor Object
        (
            [loggerCallable:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Doctrine\Bundle\MongoDBBundle\Logger\AggregateLogger Object
                        (
                            -----so on
```

Where is the result?

Comment: How many records are in Mongo; how many are you expecting on the output?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have any other information to give us ? Do you have any error output?

**Edit**

For a single result you should use :

```
$products = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')
->getManager()
->createQueryBuilder('AcmeStoreBundle:Product')
->field('name')->equals('foo')
->limit(1)
->sort('price', 'ASC')
->getQuery()
->getSingleResult();
```

For multiple results your code is good but you should iterate over the returned Cursor to get your data.

**Edit 2**

```
$products = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')
->getManager()
->createQueryBuilder('AcmeStoreBundle:Product')
->field('name')->equals('foo')
->limit(1)
->sort('price', 'ASC')
->getQuery()
->execute();

foreach ($products as $product) {
    var_dump($product);
}
```